# How does tigervnc auto-resize VNC sessions?

Tags: remote-desktop, resolution, vnc

When you open a tigervnc server session with a tigervnc client, the desktop resolution auto-resizes to match the size of the client window.

Do any other clients implement it?  Remmina doesn't seem to, but I might be missing an option.

Comment: Did you search for any config files? Look in the registry? If it's FOSS, did you look into the code?